# Only allow connections from custom clients

Tags: python, sockets, network-programming

I'm writing a Socket Server in Python, and also a Socket Client to connect to the Server.

The Client interacts with the Server in a way that the Client sends information when an action is invoked, and the Server processes the information.

**The problem I'm having, is that I am able to connect to my Server with Telnet, and probably other things that I haven't tried yet. I want to disable connection from these other Clients, and only allow connections from Python Clients. (Preferably my custom-made client, as it sends information to communicate)**

Is there a way I could set up authentication on connection to differentiate Python Clients from others?

Currently there is no code, as this is a problem I want to be able to solve before getting my hands dirty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@holdenweb has already given a good answer with basic info.

If a (terminal) software sends the bytes that your application expects as a valid identification, your app will never know whether it talks to an original client or anything else.

A possible way to test for valid clients could be, that your server sends an encrypted and authenticated question (should be different at each test!), e.g. something like "what is 18:37:12 (*current date and time*) plus 2 (*random*) hours?"
Encryption/Authentication would be another issue then.
If you keep this algorithm secret, only your clients can answer it and validate themselves successfully. It can be hacked/reverse engineered, but it is safe against basic attackers.

Comment: I've made it so the client sends back an MD5 hash of the answer to the question, and is working well! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

When a new connection is made to your server, your protocol will have to specify some way for the client to authenticate. Ultimately there is nothing that the network infrastructure can do to determine what sort of process initiated the connection, so you will have to specify some exchange that allows the server to be sure that it really is talking to a valid client process.

Comment: Well thats the thing, I have no idea how to come up with a valid example in my head. Any ideas?

Comment: Well, one very simple way would be to require the first bytes sent by the client to be "I am a valid Python client," but of course a Telnet user could also do that. Another way would be to send a string to the client on connection, requiring it do compute a response which you then verify after it has replied.

Comment: Take a look at https://mayaposch.wordpress.com/2011/10/03/design-your-own-protocol-in-five-minutes/ for a relatively non-scary introduction to protocol design. It can, of course, get much more complex than that.

Comment: About to read now, but after reading your comments, perhaps I could send a random equation, and request an MD5 hash of the answer sent back??

Comment: Search for "challenge-response" protocols - you already have the basic idea

Comment: Yes... I've so far got 3 packets setup. Data sending/recieving, authentication and connection-states (force disconnect, check if alive, etc)